# fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to run my one Python-Django app in Apcera and i'm getting below error in the middle of staging process. Apcera is actually in company's server. I tried couple sample apps in Apcera official website and it worked fine but mine just require more python package and getting this error due to pyodbc. From Google, I knew it requires ODBC header file on Server Side but not sure how to access "`/runq/sandbox/xxxx(my ID)`" and install `unixodbc-dev`.

ex) `sudo apt install unixodbc-dev`

appreciate if you can help me some. There was not much Q/A regarding Apcera/Staging with Python-Django in Google.

Typed command in console: `apc app create case-app2`
Error Msg:

```
src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
[staging]      #include <sql.h>
```

Comment: This isn't really a python issue and should probably be moved to ServerFault. Anyway, what OS is this? Ubuntu? What is the result of this command? `sudo apt-file find sql.h`

Comment: Apcera is running on Company's Server. and i am assuming it's Ubuntu. If i have access to the server machine directly, yes i can install unixodbc-dev. Unfortunately I can't access to Company's server directly (maybe i'm not allowed). in the requirements.txt file, i listed couple of python packages and downloading looks fine in staging but when it starts installing pyodbc, see this error. is there any way i can use custom packaging or install required package like unixodbc-dev in company's server remotely using other script file?

Comment: https://docs.apcera.com/packages/staging/#python -> here, explanation about staging process with python and django is too small... and not much Q/A about apcera in stackoverflow. Tried to look up any example in git web-site but failed to find good example.